# e2fsck did no solve the IO error

Tags: ubuntu, hard-disk, badblocks, e2fsck

Unit had observed IO error, hence it was rebooted. As part of the boot-up script, it tries to fix the errors with e2fsck -y option. However, even after reboot it could not correct it. And the error is -

```
File system errors left uncorrected (error code 4)
Error reading block 411649 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read) while reading directory block.
```

How to correct this? System reboot again will help or is there any other option?

Comment: Please see this forum chat: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1431853

Comment: Looks like your hard disk has failed and will need to be replaced.  Check `dmesg` for more detailed errors.

Comment: Do you have smartctl installed? It can show you (and us) the health of the disk.

Comment: No, smartctl is not installed. Same errors seen after couple of reboots, that means fsck could not fix it.